# Regexp to accept ONLY Yes or No and should not be case sensitive

Tags: regex, preg-match

Here is my regexp to accept only Yes or No (not case sensitive). Is there a better way to do it?
Thanks

```
preg_match('/^(?:Yes\b|YES\b|yes\b|No\b|NO\b|no\b)/',$input)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `i` modifier.

```
preg_match('~^(?:Yes|no)\b~i', $input);
```

Add end of the line anchor `$` if necessary.

```
preg_match('~^(?:Yes|no)$~i', $input);
```